# Finishing an argument why $(A^*v, w) = (v, Aw)$ for $A$ a square complex matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A$ be a symmetric complex matrix of size $n \times n$. The complex inner product $(a, b)$ for vectors of dimension $n$ is defined as $\sum_{i=1}^{n} \bar{a_i}b_i$.
I want to see why $(A^*v, w) = (v, Aw)$.

So far I have

$$(A^*v, w)=\sum_{i=1}^{n} (A^*v)_i^* w_i = \sum_{i=1}^{n} (\sum_{j=1}^n A_{i, j}^* v_j)^* w_i$$ $$ =
  \sum_{i=1}^{n} (\sum_{j=1}^n A_{i, j} v_j^*) w_i =\sum_{i=1}^{n} (\sum_{j=1}^n A_{j, i}^* v_j^*) w_i$$

$$(v, Aw) = \sum_{i=1}^{n} v^*_i (Aw)_i = \sum_{i=1}^{n} v_i^* (\sum_{j=1}^{n} A_{i, j} w_j) = \sum_{i=1}^{n} v_i^* (\sum_{j=1}^{n} A_{j, i}^* w_j)$$

Not sure why these two are equal. Any insights appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first line, what you actually have is
$$
\sum\limits_{j=1}^n\left(\sum\limits_{j=1}^n\overline{(A^*_{i,j}v_j)}\right)w_i=\sum\limits_{j=1}^n\left(\sum\limits_{j=1}^n\overline{v_j}A_{j,i}\right)w_i
$$
(not an asterisk, but a conjugation. When you take the conjugate of the adjoint you get the transpose.)

Your last step in your first chain of equalities you should exchange the sums
$$
\sum\limits_{j=1}^n\sum\limits_{i=1}^n\overline{v_j}(A_{j,i}w_i)=
\sum\limits_{i=1}^n\sum\limits_{j=1}^n\overline{v_j}(Aw)_j=(v,Aw).
$$

Answer (score 0):

I wrote my own answer as practice in a way that I understand, hopefully this helps someone.

$(A^*v, w) = (v, Aw)$ since
$$(A^*v, w)=\sum_{i=1}^{n} \overline{(A^*v)_i} w_i = \sum_{i=1}^{n} (\sum_{j=1}^n \overline{A^*_{i, j} v_j}) w_i = \sum_{i=1}^{n} (\sum_{j=1}^n A_{j, i} \overline{v_j}) w_i$$

whereas,
$$(v, Aw) = \bar{v}^T A w = w^T A^T \overline{v} = \sum_{i=1}^{n} (\sum_{j=1}^{n} A^T_{i, j} \overline{v_j}) w_i = \sum_{i=1}^{n}(\sum_{j=1}^{n} A_{j, i} \overline{v_j}) w_i.$$

This last equality uses the fact that for any vectors $a,b$, $a^T A b = b^T A^T a$ since the transpose of a scalar is a scalar.